# Fill a template.rss with TypoScript for RSS feed

Tags: rss, typo3, blogs, feed, typo3-7.6.x

Im using the blog extension for TYPO3 7.6.23.
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/blog/

I want to create a RSS-feed that shows the latest 3 blog articles.

I have a template Default.rss

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>{feed.title}</title>
    <description>{feed.description}</description>
    <language>{feed.language}</language>
    <link>{feed.link}</link>
    <lastBuildDate>{feed.date}</lastBuildDate>
    <f:render section="content" />
  </channel>
</rss>
```

And my setup TypoScript

```
    blog_rss_posts = PAGE
    blog_rss_posts {
        typeNum = 202
        10 = TEMPLATE
        10.template = FILE
        10.template.file = EXT:blog/Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.rss
        config {
            disableAllHeaderCode = 1
            additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
            xhtml_cleaning = none
            admPanel = 0
        }
    }
```

via

```
 20 = TEXT
 20 < tt_content.list.20.blog_posts
```

I get all my blog-posts.

The question is how can I fill my template with the right data?
I want to call domain.com/blog/?type=202 and get a RSS-Feed in XML.

What do I have to add in the TypoScript?

Answer (score 1):

1st: `20 = TEXT` is overwritten with the following `20 < tt_content.list.20.blog_posts`, so: remove it.

2nd: with this copy `20 < tt_content.list.20.blog_posts` you copied the base configuration for a plugin. as this plugin has no tt_content record all the configuration must be done in typoscript. You might use the [TSOB](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/css_styled_content/4.7/HowTo/Index.html#object-browser), to explore possible parameters and set new values for the plugin.

Comment: I explored the TSOB but I have no idea what Im searching for.
I mean I have a working blog. A feed which provides me all articles in HTML, a template for the RSS. Which step do I need in between

Comment: in TSOB you can see the configuration of the plugin which decides what is rendered. the default values can be found at `tt_content.list.20.blog_posts`. so you can see some (not all paramters need to be set) of the Paramters and identify them for modification, so you can build a configured plugin with typoscript in your page. The alternative would be a proteced page/page column, where you insert a real content element, which you can configure, and then display it with a little bit typoscript on every page or on special page types.